# Are these compile statements needed?

Tags: android, gradle

I am preparing to launch an Android application and the project gradle script has these lines

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
```

My question is are they needed? I did not type/code the filetree one, and the others may have been a result of me testing out different libraries.

My minSdkVersion is 11 and targetSdkVersion is 21.

Secondly in the defaultConfig block the applicationId is different than my project name and app name. What is this value used for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are needed, first line is for including libraries in libs folder if any, most of them are available through gradle but for those that are not this line is useful, similar to adding to buildpath in Eclipse. Second and last are default, and third is used for all google libraries, such as APIs (maps, translator, gcm etc.)

Comment: So there is no real benefit to remove them? I do not use maps or any google services in my application

Comment: Well if you don't have anything in libs folder you should be able to remove first line, but leave other three. https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html